# Create a simple script that run an executable [solved]

Tags: linux

I`m trying to create a script that create and run an executable. Is it even possible?

Something like this:

file name: test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod +x fileName
./fileName
```

that I would run

```
bash test.sh
```

but the output is

```
# bash test.sh
: No such file or directory
test.sh: line 3: ./fileName: No such file or directory
```

Normally when I do it from the command line I use the command 'sudo -i', but what I want to do is to create a script that executes the executable automatically

Comment: You are in the wrong directory? Change it with `cd`. Or your script `filename` doesn't exists

Comment: I solved using dos2unix...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create a script that creates and runs an executable. Your script seems mostly correct, but it's missing the part where it actually creates the executable file. Here's how you can modify your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a simple C program
cat <<EOF > fileName.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
EOF

# Compile the C program
gcc -o fileName fileName.c

# Give execute permission to the compiled executable
chmod +x fileName

# Run the executable
./fileName
```

This script creates a simple C program, compiles it, gives execute permission to the compiled executable, runs it, and then cleans up by removing the compiled executable and the C source file.

Save this script in a file (e.g., test.sh), give it execute permission (chmod +x test.sh), and then you can run it (./test.sh). It should output "Hello, world!" as expected.

Comment: hi, thanks but I solved using dos2unix...

Comment: Version of min also should work as you exptected